# Verilog 4 bits sum

Tags: verilog

does anybody know what are for PG and GG variables here:

```
module sum(S, Cout,PG,GG,A,B,Cin);

wire [3:0] G,P,C;

output [3:0] S;
output Cout,PG,GG;
input [3:0] A,B;
input Cin;

assign G = A & B;
assign P = A ^ B; 
assign C[0] = Cin;
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | (P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | (P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) | (P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);
assign Cout = G[3] | (P[3] & G[2]) | (P[3] & P[2] & G[1]) | (P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0]) |(P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0]);

 assign S[0] = P[0] ^ C[0];
assign S[1] = P[1] ^ C[1];
assign S[2] = P[2] ^ C[2];
assign S[3] = P[3] ^ C[3];
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a four-bit carry-lookahead adder unit. PG and GG can be Group Propagate and Group Generate. PG and GG can be given to another CLA adder unit to combine such units to form a higher bit adder. They are given as

`assign PG = P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0];`

`assign GG = G[3] | P[3] & G[2] | P[3] & P[2] | G[1] | P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0];`

More details here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookahead_Carry_Unit#16-bit_adder

Answer (score 0):

`GG` and `PG` are `output` ports which are not driven by the code that you have shown.  I can not think of a use for them.  Unless they are driven by a hierarchical specifier outside of this module (which is possible, but unusual), their value will always be unknown (x).

Perhaps the original designer had intended to use these outputs, and then forgot to remove them.